# Which the class of MVC pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller

As it known, there are Creational, Structural and Behavioural design patterns. But I didn't find which the class of MVC pattern. What should it be?

Comment: It's not a Gang of Four pattern.  It's a presentation architecture, not a design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MVC` is not a design pattern defined by `Gang of Four`. Rather it is a more high level architectural pattern which encompasses several design patterns defined by `Gang of Four`. At a minimum the MVC pattern uses `Observer` pattern which is a `Behavioral` pattern. There are some more design patterns used by MVC. Sometimes the patterns it uses may depend on the particular implementation too.

So to sum up MVC uses several design patterns defined by `Gang of Four` to achieve it's mission. Hence it is a collection of design patterns.